# External Login in facebook and get access token using asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, facebook-graph-api

How to get access token, when login into Facebook. I mean how to get Facebook access token right after login into the Facebook account. I am using asp.net core.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I found it not so useful.

Comment: did you see this also? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 6):

Firstly you can follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to config Facebook Authentication in your asp.net core application . To get the access token after login , you can firstly set `SaveTokens` to true when registering :

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
{
      facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
      facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];

      facebookOptions.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

After authentication , you can get the token in action like :

```
var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

Comment: Is there any option to change the key "access_token" to a custom one?